# Undo Alt key-press in Windows 11 Explorer and Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard, windows-explorer, windows-11

When I'm navigating my folders in explorer with the keyboard, I accidentally press the Alt key and I can access the file-menu. However after I updated to Windows 11 I get stuck there, I cannot press Alt a second time to cancel and continue navigating. I have to pick up the mouse or tab through all the way back. This also happens in Chrome and other programs.

Is this just a problem I have or is Windows 11 like this? Any solution?

Comment: I am not clear if there is an issue or not. Windows 11 is much more mouse driven than earlier operating systems and I just use my mouse

Comment: Have you tried just pressing <escape>? That should close the file menu

Comment: Hmm, I see, escape, ok. My escape is remapped with AutoHotKey to close the window.
Very annoying that I can't do it with Alt again like in Windows 10.

Comment: Try other keys after hitting Alt. For example, I find tab also closes the menu on one PC.

Comment: Tab just moves the focus like normal, it does not close

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce that behavior, as others have mentioned <kbd>ESC</kbd> should return to the previous location.

I note you mention that this is a problem because you accidentally press <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and you also mention you use AutoHotkey. You could use AutoHotkey to block an <kbd>Alt</kbd> keypress by itself.

```
$~LAlt::Send {blind}{vkFF}
```

That will prevent a naked <kbd>Alt</kbd> keypress, but still allow <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> combinations.

It also only blocks the left <kbd>Alt</kbd>, which is the one I find I accidentally hit and still allows for a naked <kbd>Alt</kbd> with the right <kbd>Alt</kbd>. If you'd prefer to block both <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys, change the AutoHotkey from <kbd>LAlt</kbd> to <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

[AutoHotkey documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/_MenuMaskKey.htm) on menu masking.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've Been having the same issue - esc doesn't do it for me either, as the menu isn't actually opened, it just selects the option without skipping back when re-pressing Alt.
I'm trying to get used to just holding Alt more as a work-around, as pressing and holding Alt kind of works if you don't single-press more than twice, and then just continue with arrow keys etc. Not as easy as Win10 though, unfortunately.
Very annoying to Tab eight times every time this happens.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm glad I'm not alone. What's up with downgrading with new windows? First they robbed us from the nice tiled Start-menu and finally yesterday I got groups in my start-menu again. 1 year late.